# How to train mobilenet-v1 quantized model to use on TF Lite

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I have re-trained a mobilenet-v1 image classification model from Tensorflow Hub, and converted it using toco for inference using Tensorflow Lite.

However, when I run inference using the tflite model, it requires a different input size than what I specified with `--input_shape`.

How can I re-train a mobilenetv1 quantized model on my own data?

Here a the steps that I attempted:

- Download the training dataset from tensorflow for poets [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#2)
- [Retrain](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) the mobilenet v1 quantized model on TF Hub using the dataset above

  `python retrain.py \
    --bottleneck_dir="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/bottlenecks/ \
    --how_many_training_steps=1000 \
    --model_dir="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/models/mobilenet_v1_050_224 \
    --summaries_dir="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/training_summaries/mobilenet_v1_050_224/ \
    --output_graph="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/retrained_mobilenet_v1_050_224.pb \
    --output_labels="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
    --tfhub_module=https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_050_224/quantops/classification/1 \
    --image_dir="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/flower_photos`
- Verify that the model is properly trained, and input/output tensor name is correct
  `python label_image.py \
    --graph="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/retrained_mobilenet_v1_050_224.pb \
    --labels="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
    --input_layer=Placeholder \
    --output_layer=final_result \
    --input_height=224 --input_width=224 \
    --image="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg`
- Convert the model to tflite

  `toco \
   --input_file="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/retrained_mobilenet_v1_050_224.pb \
   --output_file="${IMAGE_DIR}"/tf_files/mobilenet_v1_050_224_quant.tflite \
   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
   --output_format=TFLITE \
   --input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
   --input_array=Placeholder \
   --output_array=final_result \
   --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
   --input_data_type=FLOAT`

Although I specified `--input_shape=1,224,224,3`, when I run the inference, I got an error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataType (1) of input data does not match with the DataType (3) of model inputs.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast forward to 2020, the easiest way to train a TF Lite image classification model now is to use TF Lite Model Maker.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification

The output TF Lite model can be drag-and-drop into Android Studio with the ML Model Binding plugin. See the end-to-end flow in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU

Answer (score 0):

--input_data_type=""  or --input_data_types="" >> Input array type, if not already provided in the graph. Typically needs to be specified when passing arbitrary arrays to --input_arrays.

In my case it was not needed (i used MobileNet_V2 pretrained model).

You have to add few more arguments (--mean_value --std_value --default_ranges_min and --default_ranges_max ) in your command for quatization.

As mentioned in the gihub [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md) page, the following command works for me

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco --input_file=~/tf_files/retrained_graph_mobileNet_v2_100_224.pb --output_file=~/tf_files/retrained_graph_mobileNet_q_v2_100_224.tflite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_shape=1,224,224,3 --input_array=Placeholder --output_array=final_result --mean_value=128 --std_value=128 --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6
```

Comment: Can you please explain values from `--default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6`? Why `0` and `6`?

Comment: Sorry for my late response and hope you have already got to know the answer. However, I'm briefly putting this information as it might be helpful to others. MobileNet_V2 model uses Relu6 activation function and the output of each neuron is bound to be in the range between 0 and 6. Therefore, activation ranges should be contained in [0, 6]. For detail documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples#use_dummy-quantization_to_try_out_quantized_inference_on_a_float_graph_)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong,

but *datatype error* does not seem to be a problem with the shape of the input data but more of the datatype.

If you quantize a model, this means you change the datatype from float32 to int8.

Depending on how you run your model there are different types of quantization.

- Using neural processors mostly need full quantization.
  -- Meaning that input and output need to be quantized as well as the weights and the bias (bias not to int8 but int32)
- Using quantization only to make the model smaller and faster but you *don't* run it  on a neural processor, a "half" quantization is just fine. -- Meaning quantizing only the weights will do the trick.

There are also other quantization methods, but what I am aiming for is: If you did a full quantization, either you have a quantization layer included which does the transformation from float32 to int8 for you or, your model expects int8 inputs.

*edit:* I just saw that you determine the input as FLOAT. Maybe float32 would be the correct term. At least something is off with your input datatype vs first layer input type.

You can use a tool like [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to look at your input layer and see what is expected. The tool can also be used to identify how your network was quantized.

Good luck and stay save.